# FLASK button pressed - get info from FLASK and render it

Tags: python, html, flask, post

This is just a test, i am going to make the button get info from a mysqldb, but for understanding this.
So here is my text inside flask:

```
@app.route('/pythonlogin/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:

        return render_template('home.html', username=session['username'], admin=session['admin'])
   
    if request.method == 'POST' in request_form:
        test = 'testyes'
    return render_template('home.html', test=test)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

And this is from .html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Home Page</h2>
<p>Welcome back, {{ username }} {{admin}}!</p>


{% if admin == 'yes' %}
<br><p>You are a admin</p>

<br>

<div class="home">
<form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="button">


<p> {{ test }} </p>
</div>
</form>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

But nothing happens!

Comment: This don't work , and  do not understand why

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems:

This is wrong:

```
if request.method == 'POST' in request_form:
```

but this is ok:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

It means: if the request was submitted as POST (vs GET etc)

Then you have these two statements at the end:

```
return render_template('home.html', test=test)
return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

You can't have both. render_template will be run and redirect will not have a chance to run. I think this is an indentation problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful